# Conditional OrderBy

Tags: vb.net, linq, syntax

So, right now I've got a number of columns the user can sort by (Name, County, Active) and that's easy but messy.  Looks something like this...

```
        Select Case e.SortExpression
            Case "Name"
                If (isDescending) Then
                    resultsList.OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.Name).ToList()
                Else
                    resultsList.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Name).ToList()
                End If
            Case "County" ... and so on
```

what I would LIKE to do, is something more ... graceful, like this

```
Private Function SortThatList(ByVal listOfStuff As List(Of Stuff), ByVal isDescending As Boolean, ByVal expression As Func(Of Stuff)) As List(Of Stuff)
    If (isDescending) Then
        Return listOfStuff.OrderByDescending(expression)
    Else : Return listOfStuff.OrderBy(expression)
    End If
End Function
```

but it doesn't like the datatype (Of TKey) ... I've tired Func(Of stuff, boolean) (got something in c# that works nicely like that) but can't seem to get this one to do what I want.  Ideas?  What's the magic syntax?

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem, but IMO a nicer interface would be accomplished by adding an extension method which is an overload of `OrderBy` but takes an extra boolean argument which is e.g. `false` if it should order "ascendingly". So e.g. `listOfStuff.OrderBy(expression, isDescending)`...

Comment: Could you post the C# code so we can see what you're going for?

Comment: c# code thats somewhat similiar looks like this 
public List<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, an extension method that takes an extra parameter, in VB. What you were probably missing is the `(Of TSource, TKey)` after the method name, equivalent of `<TSource, TKey>` in C#.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function OrderBy(Of TSource, TKey)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), ByVal isDescending As Boolean, ByVal selector As Func(Of TSource, TKey)) As IOrderedEnumerable(Of TSource)
    Return If(isDescending, source.OrderByDescending(selector), source.OrderBy(selector))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer in c# incase anyone comes looking

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool isDescending, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    return isDescending ? source.OrderByDescending(selector) : source.OrderBy(selector);
}
```

usage

**VB**

```
listOfStuff.OrderBy(isDescending, Function(x) x.Name)
```

**C#**

```
listOfStuff.OrderBy(isDescending, x => x.Name);
```